# How do I view images copied from another server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I have a server with images that will copy images to a directory on another server with an asp.net application. This is done e.g once a day.

How do I view pictures through my asp.net application?

I have my asp.net application and a folder with images and I (the application) “don't know” the name  of the images. Would be great if I could put the pictures names in a database in my asp.net application, but do not know how I can do that when I get new image in the folder.

Can I scan the directory with the images and put the names in the database?

It would have been good to have the names of the images in the database later on if I e.g want to implement a search function.

Comment: you always can wrive WinService that will check your folder once in 10 min for ex. and put image name to db if it's not exist

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.Directory.GetFiles will return you a string array with paths to the files contained on a Directory object.

You only need to create this object with using your folder route and loop through the collection of files.